# Kotlin Gradle build with Spring Boot not publishing jars to Artifactory - only build info

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, artifactory

I'm trying to publish a Spring Boot jar to Artifactory and cannot get it to work. Here's my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

group = "com.blah"
version = "0.0.2"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.1.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") version "2.5.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
    id("com.jfrog.artifactory") version "4.13.0"
}

tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = true
}


tasks.getByName<Jar>("bootJar") {
    classifier = "application"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        setUrl("https://artifactory:443/artifactory/txo-maven-virtual") 
        credentials {               
            username = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USR") 
            password = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_PSW")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}

//publishing {
//    (publications) {
//        "mavenJava" (MavenPublication::class) {
//            from(components["java"])
//        }
//    }
//}

artifactory {
    setContextUrl("https://artifactory/artifactory")
    publish(delegateClosureOf<org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.PublisherConfig> {
        repository(delegateClosureOf<org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.DoubleDelegateWrapper> {
            setProperty("repoKey", "txo-")
            setProperty("username", System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USR"))
            setProperty("password", System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_PSW"))
            setProperty("maven", true)
        })
        defaults(delegateClosureOf<groovy.lang.GroovyObject> {
            invokeMethod("publications", "mavenJava")
        })
    })
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

This builds and pushes the build info to `artifactory/api/build` but does not push any jars.

If I uncomment the commented-out stuff, I get:

> - What went wrong: Publication with name 'mavenJava' not found.

How can I get this thing to publish my jar files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        register("mavenJava", MavenPublication::class) {
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
}
```